# Making earrings and a pendant with rubies. Materials to avoid for the prong fitting

Tags: jewelry

I bought a few cheap pear-shaped synthetic rubies and want to craft a pendant and earrings. (They [are real](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412788/how-can-i-test-if-a-ruby-is-real) and [I'm assuming as safe as CZ](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90351/cubic-zirconia-additives-and-toxicity#comment165200_90351))

[image]

<sub>(Image license: Public domain)</sub>

## What type of material should I use for the prong fittings?

I'd rather not use a very expensive metal like gold or platinum. However, I  definitely want to *avoid* [contact dermatitis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3047925/) which is usually caused by **nickel** based alloys with about 17% of females being allergic to it.

Other metals can cause allergies too, like [cobalt, palladium](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5560191/), [etc](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/are-you-allergic-to-metals-6-surprising-places-they-may-lurk/).

## Other fitting options?

I went with prongs but are there any more suitable fitting options for those gemstones? They are 10x12 mm.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wirework bezel setting or prong setting, whichever you choose.

For the choice of metal, you could use copper wire, or copper wire which has been plated in gold or silver.  These options are available from jewellery making suppliers such as [Jewellery Maker](http://www.jewellerymaker.com) and [Create & Craft](https://www.createandcraft.com)